# installed bash, keyboard keys are switched

Tags: windows, bash, keyboard

I've recently installed bash on my computer. But after the installation some signs are somehow switched.
for example under my 2/@ lays a " sign.

I want to revert this back to normal, is there somebody who can help me with this?

tnx in advance,

Niels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has your system language been changed ? With `Alt + shift` you can check if this is the case .

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution!

Comment: Amazing ! Feel free to mark the reply as the answer :)